# Android socket connection errror : connect failed: ETIMEDOUT

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I am developing an android app, that will be communicating with an wifi controler (fixed IP and PORT) using TCP , but since i don't have the controller yet. So i created a simple C# server programm that would recieve some test messages.

But when i try to open the connection in android, it gives me the Exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 1234): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

C# Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        static Socket sck;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1234));
            sck.Listen(100);
            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
            Buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(Buffer);
            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string strData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            Console.Write(strData + "\r\n");
            Console.Read();
            sck.Close();
            accepted.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Android code:

```
try 
{

    if (socket == null) {
        int SERVERPORT = 1234;
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.2");
        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT); // FAILS
    }
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Its the first time i had to work with sockets. And i am DUMB when it comes to networking things. So it probably is a simple error.

Of course i checked all the related questions with this error, but still couldnt figure this out.

I am using GenyMotion Emulator.
Using Windows 8.1 64x.
I set the firewall settings to allow the C# app to communicate throgh windows firewall (public and private).

Does anyone know the solution? Thanks

Comment: Is the ip address and port correct ?

Comment: Well, yes. "10.0.2.2"  = Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Also, if the IP would be wrong there would be a different exception

Comment: No, the exception would be exactly the same, try with a 10.50.50.50 and you'll see. Install wireshark on the server pc and check if the packages are even showing. You should be on the lookout for TCP SYN messages.

Comment: Think that Genymotion does not use 10.0.2.2. That is more for an Google emulator.